# How to refresh content of page after adding item with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, zend-framework, zend-framework2, ajaxform

I have some **url** which i add some item to another page (cart page) but by refreshing page and it works fine, now i tried to do it with Ajax, so i created an ajax function to call this URL it works and it adds my item.

**Now the problem** is i have to reload the other page (cart page) to see the product. So how to do to refresh this page after adding the item, i mean after calling this URL.

The Url : `<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product, $params); ?>`

`cart.phtml`

```
...
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="product-qty">
            <div class="custom-qty">
                <div class="btn-plus">
                    <button type="button" class="reduced items" onclick="minusQty('<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>')">
                        <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                    </button>
                    <input name="qty" id="qty-<?php echo $_product->getId()?>" maxlength="12" value="1" title="Qté" class="input-text qty" type="text">
                    <button type="button" class="increase items" onclick="plusQty('<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>')">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php $params = array('qty'=>2) // the input value ?>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add') ?>" class="button btn-cart pull-left-none" onclick="addToCartAjax('<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product, $params); ?>')" >
            <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add') ?></span></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

//JS PART
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addToCartAjax(addUrl) {
        jQuery.ajax ({
                url: addUrl,
                type : 'GET',
        })
    }
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

Content of `cart.phtml`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-main col-lg-12">
        <div class="cart">
            <fieldset>
                ...
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="first odd"><td>Item1</td></tr>
                    <tr class="last even"><td>Item2</td></tr>
                </tbody>
                ...
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT2:**

**Action controller**

```
public function addAction()
{

    if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
        $this->_goBack();
        return;
    }
    $cart   = $this->_getCart();
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    try {
        if (isset($params['qty'])) {
            $filter = new Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                array('locale' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode())
            );
            $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
        }

        $product = $this->_initProduct();
        $related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');

        /**
         * Check product availability
         */
        if (!$product) {
            $this->_goBack();
            return;
        }

        $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
        if (!empty($related)) {
            $cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
        }

        $cart->save();

        $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);

        /**
         * @todo remove wishlist observer processAddToCart
         */
        Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
            array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse())
        );

        if (!$this->_getSession()->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
            if (!$cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
                $message = $this->__('%s was added to your shopping cart.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($product->getName()));
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($message);
            }
            $this->_goBack();
        }
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        if ($this->_getSession()->getUseNotice(true)) {
            $this->_getSession()->addNotice(Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($e->getMessage()));
        } else {
            $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
            foreach ($messages as $message) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($message));
            }
        }

        $url = $this->_getSession()->getRedirectUrl(true);
        if ($url) {
            $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
        } else {
            $this->_redirectReferer(Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl());
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->_getSession()->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot add the item to shopping cart.'));
        Mage::logException($e);
        $this->_goBack();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume when you add an item to the cart you get some kind of response from your server about current items of the cart, if not you have to implement that on the server side first

1. add this to your function :

   ```
     function addToCartAjax(addUrl){
       $.ajax({
         url: addUrl,
         type: 'GET',

        })
        .done(function(response ) {
            //response - this is the response from the server
        });
    }
   ```
2. I don't know exactly what your server returns if it is html than in .done closure do this :

   ```
     .done(function(response ) {
          // response - this is the response from the server
          $('.YourCartContainer').html(response);
      });
   ```

   so if your server returns an html snippet that contains your cart items than you should insert in as html into your cart div container , but if the server returns a Json response with items than you have to loop through them with jquery and format appropriately here an example , however again I don't know what your server returns so just apply the technique :

   ```
     .done(function(response ) {
          // response - this is the response from the server
          var htmlResult = '';
          $.each(response, function( item ) {
             htmlResult += '<p>'+ item.name + '</p><br>'
          });
         $('.YourCartContainer').html(htmlResult);
      });
   ```

   So here I looped through the json and created some simple html where you get all the item names that are inside the cart, hope this helped ! if You need more info regarding your case specifically than please post what your server response looks like  !!

Comment: Thanks for you answer, i updated my question to add the html content of cart look my edit please, however you added the url `url: '/path/to/file',` In knowing that my url I pass it in parameter in my function `addToCartAjax(addUrl)`, look also the `onclick` in my button. doing it as you say I am not sure that it works.

Comment: sorry it was suppose to be `url: addUrl,` I edited it see the answer , ok now do the `.done(function(response ){ console.log(response) }) `open your console and and see what is inside your `response` and post it in your question so that I can see what you are getting from your server

Comment: It return nothing !, i have enter this : `.done(function(response ){
         console.log(response) 
        });` after `jQuery.ajax ({
                url: addUrl,
                type : 'GET',
        })`

Comment: I haven't error, if i add at the end `console.log('test');` i see it in the console

Comment: well than you need to implement it on the server , trace the Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product, $params); url , find a function that is responsible for adding to cart in the end of that function query the database or session where ever your cart items are stored and then json_decode() the result and return it , otherwise it is not possible to do ajax rendering if your server does not return any data about the cart items

Comment: Please, look again my edit 2, i added the `addAction()`i tried to `var_dump($cart)` after `$cart->save();` but i get nothing

Comment: Hey, it works now i added `json_decode($cart);` before `$cart->save();` and i get a response in console and my content refresh fine but i just put `.done(function(response ) {
         jQuery('.container').html(response);
        });` not for the json one your 2nd exemple and it works its normal ? can i use `success : function(data) {
                    jQuery('.container').html(data);
                    console.log(data);
                }` instead of `.done(function(response ) {
         jQuery('.container').html(response);
        });` ?

Comment: Yes you can use `.success` as well `.done` will be executed in any case , success will only return a successful server response